# A repeating document.write that asks how many times to repeat

Tags: javascript, html

Faced a problem. On the site, i need to generate such a number of certain lines (via document.write("Welcome to my page") ) that the user will tell through the dialog box, when dialog box opening on the page. All this happens through <script> ... </script>. I tried it in different ways, but nothing works. Help me, please.

```
 confirm("Specify how many times to repeat?');
 var run() = promt("How many times? {value}') 
function run(){
     let value = document.getElementById('count').value
     if(confirm(Run block ${value} times?)) {
        while(value < 0){
            document.write(Welcome to my page!<br>')}
     }
}
```

A friend suggested this, but it doesn't work either.

```
 let res = prompt('How many times?',1)
    if(!res || isNaN(Number(res)) || res < 0) {
        alert('Invalid quantity entered')
        location.reload()
return
    }
    res = Math.round(Number(res))
    while (res > 0){
        document.write(`Welcome to my page!<br>')}
        res--
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `var run()`?

Comment: Do you see that the brackets are not matching: `"How many times? {value}'`?

Answer (score 0):

You completely misunderstood Javascript. The initial code looks like rubbish.

Is the code below what you want to achieve?

```js
alert('You`ll be prompted to specify how many times to repeat the cycle.');
const value = document.getElementById('count')?.value || 1;

const numOfRuns = confirm(`As many as this: ${value}`) ? value : (new Number(prompt('How many times to repeat the cycle?')));

for (let i = 0; i < numOfRuns; i++) {
  document.write('Welcome to my page!<br>');
}
```